# Why am I receiving this error when trying to install pyquery python module?

Tags: python, module, installation, pip, pyquery

I'm using the following command

`!pip install pyquery`

I'm able to install other modules.  Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

---

```
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
Compile failed: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
creating var
creating var/folders
creating var/folders/p1
creating var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn
creating var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T
cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/xmlXPathInit9XZ4sL.c -o var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/xmlXPathInit9XZ4sL.o
/var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/xmlXPathInit9XZ4sL.c:1:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xpath.h' file not found
#include "libxml/xpath.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
*********************************************************************************
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
*********************************************************************************
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/pip-build-nn9QXj/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/pip-X97yGE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/p1/xg17tts541n1__p_srg1n2j80000gn/T/pip-build-nn9QXj/lxml

Comment: you have to install libxml first.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this reference http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=297730 ,

I was tried installing libffi-devel, libxml2-devel, libxslt-devel and it solved the issue. I'm using CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

> src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h'
> file not found
>
> ## include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

I had encountred this type of errors. In most cases installing  development package of shared libraries the module requires fix it.

In Debian libxml2-dev has all the header files of libxml2 pacakge.
libxml2:amd64/jessie 2.9.1+dfsg1-5 uptodate
libxml2-dev:amd64/jessie 2.9.1+dfsg1-5 uptodate

lxml module requires libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev.